# Mongodb count Documents

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to count all documents that match my query, my current code looks like this:

```
   Document query = new Document();
        query.append("Stats.kills", new Document()
                .append("$gte", 547.0)
        );
        int i = 0;
        Document sort = new Document();
        sort.append("Stats.kills", -1.0);


        collection.find(query).sort(sort).into(new ArrayList<Document>(), new SingleResultCallback<ArrayList<Document>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResult(ArrayList<Document> result, Throwable t) {
                if(t != null) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                }
                consumer.accept(result.size());

            }
        });
```

I am just wondering if there is a better way to do this, maybe mongodb has a feature for this, i didn't find anything so I asked on stackoverflow now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using .find and .count?

```
db.collection.find({query}).count()
```

Pretty sure that it should give you requested result.