# Documents Count with a condition in Spring Boot & MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm new to SpringBoot and MongoDb,
I have a document like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("609a33c509bdea32555b6b87"),
    "title" : "test",
    "text" : "test text",
    "opened" : true,
    "reserved" : true,
    "createDate" : ISODate("2021-05-11T07:35:33.098Z"),
    "updateDate" : ISODate("2021-05-11T07:35:40.770Z")
}
```

I want to **count** documents with `updateDate > (createDate + 1 month)`

Please help me with suggestions or some code samples?

Comment: Hi, this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906002/mongodb-count-documents

Comment: you can add a filter option and then a project field